# Timeouts on Ajax calls only on iOS and only on one specific mobile carrier (Rogers/Fido)

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ajax, xmlhttprequest

We have a web application making ajax requests to a backend and we get frequent but intermittent timeouts only when on an **iPhone/iPad** and only when using **one** specific mobile carrier (Rogers/Fido in Quebec, Canada).

We completely isolated the problem out of our application in this very simple, pure Javascript JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6aancdwu/

- On iOS and with a Rogers/Fido simcard, slowly clicking the TEST button will end up with one of the 5 calls getting stuck and timeouting within a few minutes (sometimes right away, sometimes it takes a little more time for it to happen).
- We tested with the same simcard in an Android device and no timeout even after thousands of calls.
- We tested on the same iOS device with a wide range of simcards from other carriers and cannot reproduce the timeouts event after thousands.
- We tested in many different physical locations and many iOS devices and the problem is the same.
- We tested on iOS 11 and iOS 9, same problem.
- We confirmed that the calls timeouting do not make it to the server.
- We tested with jQuery.ajax(), direct XmlHttpRequests and with fetch(), same problem.

We don't know what to try anymore, who to contact at Rogers and whether they will want to spend time investigating this.

Anyone has an idea what the cause could be and why it happens only on iOS + Rogers?
Is there anything else we could try?
If anyone is using an iPhone and Rogers/Fido, can you reproduce the problem with the JSFiddle?

We'd rather not implement an auto-cancel-and-retry solution because some of our calls can sometimes be a little long and we'd end up cancelling good calls.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return go();">TEST</a>
<br><br>
<div id="output">waiting for action</div>

var count = 0;

function go() {
    count = 0;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "0/5";

    var q1 = sendAjax();
    var q2 = sendAjax();
    var q3 = sendAjax();
    var q4 = sendAjax();
    var q5 = sendAjax();  
    return false;
}

function sendAjax() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {    alert("TIMEOUT"); xhr.abort(); }, 30000);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            count++;
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = count + "/5";

            if (xhr.status === 200) {
            } else {
                alert("ERROR, " + "status: " + xhr.status + ", statusText: " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        }
    };       

    xhr.open("GET", "/echo/js/?_=" + new Date().getTime() + "&js=hello");
    xhr.send();
    return xhr;
}
```